# Outofmemory exception while reading an excel file having more than 90k records

Tags: java, excel, rowcount

I want to find the total row count from excel. Getting out of memory exception

```
         try {
                InputStream myxls = new FileInputStream("File path");

                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(myxls);
                System.out.println(ele.productHierarchyText());
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet Name");
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);

                int colNum = row.getLastCellNum();
                System.out.println("Total Number of Columns in the excel is : " + colNum);

                rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
                System.out.println("Total Number of Rows in the excel is : " + rowNum);
         }
```

Comment: Add link and/or tag for the library you are using to parse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have enough memory allocated to your JVM. Since it reads 90k records at the same time and tries to keep them in heap memory, it should have sufficient heap memory to accommodate those records.

Heap memory can be increased using -Xmx flag. You need to make sure that sufficient memory is allocated for heap and non-heap for your application to avoid outofmemoryerror.

For more details, you can check https://outofmemoryerror.io/